# Filter rows with same column value but IDs are not the biggest

Tags: sql, postgresql, go-gorm

I have a Postgres table that looks like this:

| id | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |

I want to get rows that only have the biggest `id` (primary key) where column `a` values are different but all in a list of numbers, i.e. expected output for rows where a are 1 and 3:

| id | a |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 |

How to write a SQL statement to fill this need?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE a IN (1, 3) ...
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are only 1 and 3 values considered for the field "*a*"?

Comment: `Select MAX(id), a FROM Table WHERE a in (1,3) GROUP BY a` not sure about Postgres, but in MSSQL if you group by A first - then Max on `Id` will get Max from the group.